# Pipes or colons in HTML title tags?

Tags: seo, title, usability, delimiter

Other than esthetics, are there any valid reasons to choose pipes vs colons in an HTML `<title>` tag, or vice-versa? Usability? SEO?

Example:

```html
<title>Example.com | Top 10 list of stuff</title>
```

or

```html
<title>Example.com: Top 10 list of stuff</title>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how you intent to use this?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add "html TITLE tag" in the description. Examples added.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I knew what you meant.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): [Which symbol should I use in the title: "|" or "-"?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/26849/17633)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it’s only colon vs. pipe: **Use the pipe.**

#### 1. The colon might (more) often be part of the page title.

It might be confusing to have two colons. Example for an article called "Top 10: Songs":

> Example.com: Top 10: Songs

It seems as if "Top 10" would be some kind of second-level category here.

#### 2. The site title should come *after* the page title. The colon wouldn’t make sense anymore.

As often only the first part of the title is shown to users (e.g., as part of the tab label in browsers) or users only read the first part (e.g., in search result lists), it’s more useful to see the beginning of the article/page than the site.  Otherwise users wouldn’t be able to find the page they are looking for when they have several pages of your site open:

> [Exampl…] [Exampl…] [Exampl…] [Exampl…] [Exampl…]

So if you agree to switch the positions, then it wouldn’t make sense anymore to use a colon:

> Top 10 list of stuff: Example.com

So it should be:

> Top 10 list of stuff | Example.com

Comment: That first point is a really good point, particularly from a usability standpoint.

Answer (score 10):

I would think neither would make a difference except for preference. Search engines are  looking at word boundries (programming term) when parsing a string and would not recognize these characters as either a word nor a part of an HTML tag and likely will ignore them completely. From an SEO perspective, they would likely be totally ignored.

[Update]

It seems that Google is taking `title` tags with pipes [|] and taking it as a keyword list. This is a fairly new development likely in response to the use of pipes [|] and how they are used. It is not clear if this happens every time however. If you put your domain name (with or without a TLD) as the last element, Google will brand the title with your domain name and a colon [:] in the beginning of the title and remove it as the last element. For example: a title tag of *cakes | chocolate | bunt | example* should appear as *example.com: cakes | chocolate | bunt*. You will need to experiment with this. I have an experiment going on now and it is too early to post the results here. But this is well known so far. This does not seem to apply to colons [:] and commas [,].

Comment: My guess is that it's most likely a click through thing on SERPs, I swear I've seen google re-arrange title tags to the colon format, even if I used pipes in the actual title tag.

Comment: It may be that a Google programmer decided that pipes are just another condition that he did not want to write much code for and therefore just did a regular expression substitute substituting a pipe for a colon. There may actually be a good reason for this that you and I are unaware of. Who knows. Sometimes the answer is as simple as that.

Comment: @DanGayle: The title that appears in the SERPs is not necessarily related to the `title` element of your page. Google is likely to change the title that appears in the SERPs to more closely reflect what the user is searching for.

Comment: Yes of course, however, I noticed that Google will most likely use the title if it is not too long and not too short, and not just a list of keywords. It has been my experience that this will more than likely always happen if the title is an honest one.

Comment: That's a very interesting new find there, and it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @DanGayle I am not a keyword title sorta guy, but I am trying it to see what happens. I am not including a reference to my domain name as not to confuse the domain names I am already using in my title tags. It will take a while to see what happens. The last keyword based experiment I did tanked me in the SERPs. Let's see if this works better. I prefer conversational titles of course. I could switch back in minutes if I had to. But again I will have to wait for Google to decide I am not a spammer. ;-) I'm not. Really I'm not. Honest. Would I lie to you?

Comment: I'd rather learn from someone in the trenches than some theoretical backseat webmaster :)

Comment: @DanGayle Yeah. I know what you mean. I have recently begun hating the "me too" SEO bloggers that parrot garbage all over the place and the SEO topic de' jure theorist bloggers that pull stuff from their nether regions. I noticed that 1 month after Google announced the demise of the author tag, that new blog posts were added telling us how to implement the tag and the SEO advantages of using the tag. There were new posts just last week! Then people come here all confused and do not believe what we tell them. Kinda sad really. I try and set the record straight. Does not always work though.