# When your brand name is long, is it still a good idea to append it to every page title?

Tags: seo, title

I am developing a new website.

The part of the title that contains the company name, which is to be appended to the title of every page, news article etc. is 31 characters long. And since we want to keep our page titles under/equal to 55-60 chars for good SEO, that gives us about 30 chars for the article title.

Should I remove the name of the company, or shorten it, so I can have more descriptive article titles? Or is it not really a problem?

Comment: Why do you want the company name repeated on every single page? it's pointless and will actually lower your CTR. Use real wording to describe what's on the page, Google will not reward extra for repeating.

Comment: @SimonHayter This is exactly what I initially though. I just needed to convince somebody else of that. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Should every page on my site have our company name in the title?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/76788/17633)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we normally do, is `page title • companyname`. We try to make the page title a max of 55-60 chars, all the remaining space on the SERP is the companyname.

We choose for this because when there is some room, you namedrop your name for that keyword, which is just as important as SEO itself (IMO).

I suggest you try to shorten your company name, sometimes you can use an abbreviation of some sort, increasing the effect of the previous paragraph.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider that. Though I want to see if anybody else has input first.

Comment: Thank you, again. I presented a compromise, a decision was made, and now a much shortened version is being appended. Only 10 chars now.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I like to include the company name in the title. However, if the title is getting too long and it's getting truncated then I just remove the "• company" from the end. Works well for me like that.

Answer (score -1):

If you will use company name at the end of title of every page. Company name will not be truncated, instead the title will be truncated. The number of characters your company name will cover, will be replaced by title characters.

```
ABC Service Online in USA | CompanyName
```

It would appear like this :

```
ABC Service Online......|CompanyName
```

Comment: While this issue has long been resolved, I would argue that for most pages (except perhaps the home page) the content is of greater importance than the company name. You only have a few words to persuade the user to click on your site in search results, amongst other pages trying to do the very same thing.