# Prevent Google from replacing "|" with ":" in search results

Tags: google-search, search-results, title

I have a title of 34 characters. I noticed that Google replaced the pipe `|` separator with colon `:`.

I like pipe separator more. Should I use `&nbsp;|&nbsp;` to make it explicit? Will this help?

Comment: No it will not. The pipe character has a special function. See: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59797/pipes-or-colons-in-html-title-tags/59799#59799

Comment: As with the [description tag](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101519/google-doesnt-display-contents-of-description-tag-in-search-resutls), Google doesn't necessarily use the value of the `title` tag you have defined in the code as the _title_ that is displayed in the SERPs.