# Why Is Shopify Adding My Store Name Automatically At The End?

Tags: technical-seo, shopify, title-attribute

I've recently opened a store selling Clothes, and am trying to improve on our SEO strategy.

I've been going through the Page Titles of all our products and making sure they all follow this format:

Product Name | Category | Brand Name

Now when I open the website and go to one of the product pages and hover over the tab in the browser, the little popup describing the Page Title reads:

Product Name | Category | Brand Name - Store Name

Does anyone know why it's adding the extra "-" with the store name? I don't think this extra text will be displayed on a google search for a specific page, but I can't test it yet because Google seems to take a while to update the changes I've made.

**When I go theme.liquid I see this code** https://prnt.sc/b5Qpu-Z42MYX

Answer (score 1):

Shopify puts the store name there because having your brand name at the end of every page title is an SEO best practice.

"Product Name | Category | Brand Name" is unlikely to be unique to your site.  Many sites are going to have a page about this product with the product name, brand name, and possibly category in the title.  Google likes unique page titles. Your page will not rank well if Google thinks the title is too similar to other page titles.

Showing your own brand name in the search results will entice people to click.  Searchers like to know what site they are clicking to. Putting the brand in the title increases engagement with your search listing. As your brand becomes better known, this effect increases.

Having your brand prominently in the search results is free advertising. You don't want to pass up an opportunity to get your brand name in front of more people, even the ones who don't click through to your site.

Finally, if you don't put your brand name in your title, Google will likely try to rewrite your title to put it there for you.  Your brand name will appear in the search results whether or not you put it in the title.  If you put it there, it is less likely that Google will mutilate your title when putting it there for you.  See [Title tag different from title appearing in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14415/title-tag-different-from-title-appearing-in-google)

Comment: But I use pipe "|" manually and also add my brand name manually on the title. Shopify generate brand name with dash "-". That's why I want to remove them.

Comment: `|` or `-` makes little or no difference to SEO.  See [Which symbol should I use in the title: "|" or "-"?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26849/which-symbol-should-i-use-in-the-title-or) Even having mixed separators in the title is very common.

Comment: Thanks, man. I was worried about it. And now, I delete all of the brand names which I was add manually in my store.

Answer (score 1):

Most Shopify themes automatically add your store’s name to every single page at the end of the title for SEO.

However, depending on your SEO strategy, this can be an unwanted feature. Fortunately, it’s very simple to get that fixed.

Editing the title in your theme’s code

- In your Shopify Admin go to online store > themes > actions > edit
  code
- In your theme.liquid file, find the tag (press CTRL + F or
  command + F on Mac to search)
- Replace the entire line of the  tag with the following code:

In this article you'll find this code: https://ezfycode.com/blog/shopify-remove-your-shop-name-from-the-website-title